# Is there an Excel add-in that allows me to create a survey and send it directly from Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, plugins, survey

Is there an Excel add-in that allows me to create a survey and send it directly from Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out CooWire, www.coowire.com. I think this is what you are looking for.